# Bash script that uses whois command gets "Servname not supported..." error on docker

Tags: bash, docker, whois

It's my first Docker image, I put there my own bash script. This script uses the `whois` command. After docker runs my script, I have some errors. Probably I made mistake on my dockerfile. Script works well on my ubuntu. 
Should I add the `/etc/services` file to my image?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
ADD ./ip_info /usr/src/ip_info
ADD ./ip_info /bin/ip_info
RUN apt-get update &&  apt-get -y install whois
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/ip_info
CMD ["/usr/src/ip_info"]
```

error:

```
getaddrinfo(whois.ripe.net): Servname not supported for ai_socktype
```

Answer (score 9):

I fixed it by

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ntp
```

to dockerfile.

Comment: `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends netbase`

is enough. That package contains the needed files /etc/protocols and /etc/services. The ntp package works because it depends on netbase.